# Word or phrase for pile of accumulated rubble under vertical cave opening

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In caves whose openings are in the ceiling of the cave, there is typically a conical pile of rubble underneath the opening from where things have fallen into the hole over a long period of time. What is the name of this pile? I think it's either one or two words and may be something like 'rubble tower'.

Answer (score 1):

The general term for loose rock that naturally accumulates at the bottom of a hill is ***scree***. This isn't specific to caves, though, and doesn't suggest an accumulation directly below an opening. That said, it could be used to describe the material itself that is accumulating.